# FB.login not returning anything

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm calling FB.login with the following code:

```
FB.init({
    appId: "***************",
    nativeInterface: CDV.FB,
    useCachedDialogs: false
});

FB.login(function(response){
    console.log(response)
} , {scope: 'user_events'})
```

But I'm not getting any response object. The login is called and passes the user through the login process, but upon completion there is no object. I have no idea how to troubleshoot this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: what is "nativeInterface" and "useCachedDialogs"? never saw that in any docs. i suggest using the official parameters from the facebook docs.

Comment: I don't know I'm using it inside of a phonegap app and found that inside of a blog post somewhere. Doesn't work without it.